# How to avoid empty extra browser opens when running parallel tests with TestNG

Tags: browser, parallel-processing, webdriver, testng

While I'm running parallel test cases using TestNG and selenium-webdriver, there are some browser instances that open empty and doesn't close even after the execution finish. I have read several topics on different forums asking about similar problems but none of them seems to be the same issue.

Also seems like more empty browsers are open when I add more test to the suite. I'm not sure what of the following information will be relevant for this problem but I will try to provide a complete picture of what I have:

- I'm using (as mentioned) TestNG - webdriver.
- I'm working with page objects pattern.
- I'm running my automation from a javafx interface, which allow the user to select some options.
- I'm using ChromeDriver to emulate mobile devices.
- I'm using a local thread of the driver which allow me to use an exclusive static driver for each test.
- No empty browser are open when I don't run in parallel.

This is my TestNg.xml:

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="4">
<test name="Test">
<groups>
     <run>
        <!-- Use include to specify what you want to run or exclude to not run the mentioned group(s) -->
        <include name="fullRegression"/>
        <exclude name="brokenOrDevelopment"/>
     </run>
  </groups>
<packages>
    <!-- Packages who contains the test cases classes -->
    <package name="Test"/>       
</packages>
```

This is the class which create the driver instance

```
public class TestCaseConfiguration {
 protected HomePageObjects homePage = null;
 protected DesiredCapabilities  capabilities;
 protected ExtentReports REPORTMANAGER;
 protected ExtentTest REPORT;

 public static ThreadLocal<ChromeDriver> driver;

 @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
 public void setup() throws InterruptedException {

     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/Tools/chromedriver.exe");//chrome driver version 2.20 | We need to have a relative path since no all the user will have the driver on C: 

     capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
     Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
     mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", Constants.DEVICE);
     Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

     capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

     /**
      * dirver is a ThreadLocal<ChromeDriver>. This allows the driver to be static and available for the complete project, and exclusive for each thread. 
      */
     driver=new ThreadLocal<ChromeDriver>()
                {
                    @Override
                    protected ChromeDriver initialValue()
                    {
                        return new ChromeDriver(capabilities); 
                    }
                };
     driver.get().manage().deleteAllCookies();
     driver.get().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.get().navigate().to(Constants.DOMAIN);

     homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver.get(), HomePageObjects.class);
 }

 @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
 public void close() throws InterruptedException {           
    driver.get().close();
    driver.get().quit();  
 }
```

}

This class is extended by each test case class. The tests run as expected, the only problem seems to be the extra browser instances.

Doesn't anyone know how can I avoid that issue or if I'm doing something wrong?
Thanks for the help.

[This is how the browser looks when open empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNwrD.png)

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new `ThreadLocal<ChromeDriver>` instance and reassigning `driver` each time `setup` runs. Imagine the following scenario where `setup` is called in parallel by multiple threads:

1. Thread0 creates a `ThreadLocal<ChromeDriver>` instance, assigns it to `driver`, and calls `driver.get()`. One browser is now open.
2. Thread1 creates a `ThreadLocal<ChromeDriver>` instance, assigns it to `driver` (replacing the one assigned to it by Thread0), and calls `driver.get()`. Two browsers are now open, one per `ThreadLocal` instance.
3. Thread0 calls `driver.get()` again but `driver` no longer references the same `ThreadLocal` instance so a new browser is opened. Three browsers are now open, one in an "orphaned" `ThreadLocal` instance and two in the referenced `ThreadLocal`.

Now imagine that scenario but with more than two threads! You'll have lots of "orphaned" `ThreadLocal` instances floating around, some of which having a `ChromeDriver` instance associated with some thread(s) but no objects on any threads with references to the `ThreadLocal` in order to "get" them.

To fix the problem I recommend marking `driver` as `final` and assigning a `ThreadLocal` instance to it once.

e.g.

```java
public class TestCaseConfiguration {
    protected HomePageObjects homePage = null;
    protected ExtentReports REPORTMANAGER;
    protected ExtentTest REPORT;

    public static final ThreadLocal<ChromeDriver> driver;
    private static final Set<ChromeDriver> drivers = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    static {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/Tools/chromedriver.exe");//chrome driver version 2.20 | We need to have a relative path since no all the user will have the driver on C:

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", Constants.DEVICE);
        Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

        /**
         * dirver is a ThreadLocal<ChromeDriver>. This allows the driver to be static and available for the complete project, and exclusive for each thread.
         */
        driver = new ThreadLocal<ChromeDriver>() {
            @Override
            protected ChromeDriver initialValue() {
                ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
                drivers.add(chromeDriver);
                return chromeDriver;
            }
        };
    }

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get().manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get().navigate().to(Constants.DOMAIN);

        homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver.get(), HomePageObjects.class);
    }

    @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void close() throws InterruptedException {
        for (ChromeDriver chromeDriver : drivers) {
            try {
                chromeDriver.quit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @mfulton26, thanks your code actually works pretty good and new the problem with the extra browsers seems to be solved. In order to apply your suggestion I also need to make a modification for the '@AferMethod' and replace it for '@AfterSuite' this because using the aftermethod current code the driver stopped working after the first 'driver.get().close()' however now for some reason the browser are not being closed even when the code is present on the '@AfterSuite' method I have tried different ways to "solve" this issue but without luck. Do you know any idea what the issue is?

Comment: Oh yeah... ha, I should have though of that. I will update my code example in a bit.

Comment: @YohanDesanti I've updated the example to keep track of the set of all drivers and quit them in an `@AfterSuite` (and not an `@AfterMethod`). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i created separate method in libFile which i call in every testcase.. 
@Libraryfile

```
//Variable declaration
WebDriver driver=null;

protected WebDriver getDriverInstance(){
   driver=new FirefoxDriver();
   return driver;
}
```

@testcase class - i am calling above method in @BeforeMethod
    //Variable declaration

```
WebDriver driver=null;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp(){
 driver=getDriverInstance();

}
```

this has solved my Multiple empty browser instances